# move cursor in matplotlib window with keyboard stroke

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to move the cursor in a Python matplotlib window by a (data) pixel at a time (I'm displaying a 2D image), using the keyboard arrow keys. I can trap the keyboard keypress events, but how do I reposition the cursor based on these events?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make MatPlotLib react to key events immediately.

Another solution is print a 'Cursor' or marker line on the plot, and change its coordinates with the mouse events. Eg. draw a vertical line, and update its X coordinates with the left and right keys. You can then add a label with the X coordinate along the line, and other nice tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to solve my issue: I trap keystroke events, and when I get the arrow keys, I use the autopy (http://www.autopy.org) package to move the mouse in a platform-independent way. I haven't gone into autopy to see how this is done, but I believe it is done in C code. autopy moves cursor in display pixel coordinates, but the matplotlib transformations can be used to transform into data pixel coordinates.